# Unwanted page refresh with webpack5 in next js

Tags: next.js

When I turn on webpack5 and call internal api(/api/*) from page after first render, the page refreshes and logs Refreshing page data due to server-side change. after refreshing once, it works fine as webpack4.

Expected Behavior
The page should not refresh on api call after first render.

Answer (score 2):

I recently updated to Next JS 12 and suddenly started encountering this issue also. I'm not sure if it's necessarily related to that as I believe Next JS 11 was also using Webpack 5 for HMR, but they certainly switched over to socket communication for hot reloading, rather than server sent events as they had with previous versions. [https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#nextjs-hmr-connection-now-uses-a-websocket]

I have a file `/inc/paths.js` where I am organizing and exporting URI path string variables for different resources in my app. There were a number of paths in that module which were also being utilized by parts of my `/api` scripts, namely object keys for AWS S3 bucket paths. So, this module was being imported by not only React components in the `/pages` directory and elsewhere, but also to the modules in the `/api` directory. **By moving all the variables used by the `/api` modules into their own file and making sure that none of those variables are imported by React components or pages**, the error seems to have disappeared for me.

This may be related to this quote from Vercel:

> Finally, if you edit a file that's imported by files outside of the
> React tree,  Fast Refresh will fall back to doing a full reload. You
> might have a file which  renders a React component but also exports a
> value that is imported by a non-React component. For example, maybe
> your component also exports a constant, and a non-React utility file
> imports it. In that case, consider migrating the constant to a
> separate file and importing it into both files. This will re-enable
> Fast Refresh to work. Other cases can usually be solved in a similar
> way.
> https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh

Although the logic doesn't quite match up, it leads me to believe there is something occurring along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I updated next.js due to the console warning I get whenever next.js run, telling me its using using weppack 4 instead of 5

You can still use webpack 4 by changing it from your next config as it's an update issue

Answer (score 0):

On the client page, I changed to call the internal API by useEffect() hook to fetch data, instead of triggering the data-fetch function by onclick.  I found the issue was gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).